# Сменить текст при нажатии

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне надо поменять текст при нажатии, сейчас у меня нет обратного действия, чтоб при нажатии было скрыть, при втором нажатии подробнее. Заранее благодарен.

```
$('.link_slider_2').click(function () {
   (this).text('Скрыть');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и без jquery сделать.

```js
function changeText(ev) {
    if(ev.getAttribute('data-show') === "true") {
        ev.innerText = "Подробнее"
        ev.setAttribute('data-show', "false"); 
    }
    else {
        ev.innerText = "Скрыть"
        ev.setAttribute('data-show', "true"); 
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changeText(this)" data-show="true">
    Скрыть
</button>
```

Или с jquery:

```js
$('.link_slider_2').click(function () {
    if($(this).attr('data-show') === "true") {
        $(this).text("Показать");
        $(this).attr('data-show', "false"); 
    }
    else {
        $(this).text("Скрыть");
        $(this).attr('data-show', "true"); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="link_slider_2" data-show="true">
    Скрыть
</button>
```

Comment: Зачем давать плохой пример ставя слушатели не в скрипте? И зачем использовать innerText, а не textContent?

Comment: @And [test1](https://jsperf.com/textcontent-or-innertext), [test2](https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-innertext/42), [test3](https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-innertext/17)

Comment: Я так понял что setAttribute нужен только для не стандартных атрибутов, а получать и изменять атрибуты лучше через свойства. И если уже ставить data-*, то через dataset.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, у атрибутов поддержка полная, а у датасета - не очень (хотя все современные поддерживают).

Comment: Вроде [норм поддержка](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) или IE 10 и IE 9 еще так важны? Еще интересно, babel вместе с preset-env ставит полифилы на подобные штуки DOM если указать поддерживать старые браузеры в browserslist?

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто менять свойство элемента(объекта). свойство onclick можно использовать если знаешь что не будет больше одного слушателя события, или я не прав?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
// btn.textContent хранит стартовый текст кнопки
const text = [btn.textContent, 'Подробнее'] 

// вариант короче если надо давать только один обработчик клика
btn.onclick = changeText 

function changeText ({ target }) {
  /* приводит число к противоположному булевому типу и приводит к обратно числу(служит как индекс)
   * вначале будет undefined, но это всеравно приведет к 1(строка 'Подробнее')
   * присваивать в объект элемента проще чем к data-* атрибуту 
   */ 
  target.state = +!target.state
  // textContent быстрее. Берется текст из массива по индексу 
  target.textContent = text[target.state] 
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" type="button">
    Скрыть
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Хорошая идея с `dataset`, можно сделать немного по другому, чтоб не харкодить в скрипт и было применимо на другие кнопки этого же класса. Записал второй вариант текста в атрибут `data-label="Показать"` и по клику менял их местами.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    var text = $btn.text();
    var label = $btn.data('label');
    
    $btn.text(label).data('label', text);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-label="Показать" class="btn">
  Скрыть
</button>

<button type="button" data-label="Пока" class="btn">
  Привет
</button>

<button type="button" data-label="Два" class="btn">
  Один
</button>
```